# Is there a way to save info to mysql before the closing of the modal(on timer 4 secs) without the use of submit button

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When the modal opens automatically a textbox has a data or info. 
I want to save that to mysql before the modal closes or after it closes without using a submit button. Is there a way to do this using jquery i suppose?

Im using laravel, resource controller feature

here is my code with button

```
$('#student_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('ajaxdata.postdata') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error.length > 0)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.error[count]+'</div>';
                    }
                    $('#form_output').html(error_html);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#form_output').html(data.success);
                    $('#student_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#action').val('Add');
                    $('.modal-title').text('Add Data');
                    $('#button_action').val('insert');
                    $('#student_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: an an ajx call to the code that calls the modal

Comment: When the modal opens... there's some code behind it to open the modal, right? Even if the modal opens automatically there's something calling it. That code can send a POST back to server with the message you want to persist on database.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by hooking up to the modal event in bootstrap.try this out,

```
$('#youModalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get the value from the input box
  // make the ajax call here
})
```

for more information go to this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

Comment: this is my submit with button

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are referring to?